# invalid_taxonomy for $term on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in my theme for displaying the post tags in a file called `tags-item.php`

```
<li class="tags-item">
  <a class="tags-link" href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( $term->name ); ?></a>
</li>
```

and this file is called from :

```
<?php $post_tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), array( 'category', 'product', 'post_tag' ) ); ?>
      <?php if ( $post_tags ) : ?>
        <div class="tags">
          <h4 class="tags-heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Tagged under:', 'cx' ); ?></h4>
          <ul class="tags-list">
            <?php
              foreach ( $post_tags as $term ) {
                include( locate_template( 'template-parts/tags-item.php' ) );
              }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/tags-->
      <?php endif; ?>
```

This was working fine. Now I migrated to Wp-Engine and upgraded the Wordpress version to 6.2 and it is now running on PHP 8. When I go to the post page, I am getting an error :

`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /nas/content/live/blogsstg/wp-content/themes/my-theme/template-parts/tags-item.php:6`

The code referred here is the code that I have mentioned in the start. Now I have printed the `$term` variable and I am getting

```
Array
(
    [invalid_taxonomy] => Array
        (
            [0] => Invalid taxonomy.
        )

)
```

This is happening inconsistently. So I need to make any changes here to make the tags work ?